# Titanium inApp purchases with urbanirship

Tags: titanium, in-app-purchase, urbanairship.com

We are developing an app using Appclerator titanium. We have a free version of the app and an inApp purchases to get more features. On success of purchase we need to download a content( mainly an xml file) and read them and update the database. How is this possible using titanium.
n
Also does any ]one has a sample code for the urbairship in app purchases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use the storekit module for Titanium.

You can download it free from the marketplace:
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/794

The download has the instructions on how to use it.